# mount a component only once and not unmount it again

Tags: react-native

Perhaps what I think can solve my issue is not the right one. Happy to hearing ideas. I am getting:

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and async task in a useEffect cleanup function
```

and tracked it down to one component that is in my headerRight portion of the status bar. I was under the impression it mounts only once. Regardless, the component talks to a syncing process that happens and updates the state. For each status of the sycing, a different icon is displayed.

dataOperations is a NativeModules class that talks to some JAVA that does the background syncing and sends the status to RN.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

import DataOperations from "../../../../lib/databaseOperations"

const CommStatus: () => React$Node = () => {
  let [status, updateStatus] = useState('');
  const db = new DataOperations();

  const onCommStatus = (event) => {
    status = event['status'];
    updateStatus(status);
  };

  const startSyncing = () => {
    db.startSyncing();
  };


const listner = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
  'syncStatusChanged',
  onCommStatus,
);

 //NOT SURE THIS AS AN EFFECT
  const removeListner = () =>{
    DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener(listner)
  }

  //REMOVING THIS useEffect hides the error
  useEffect(() => {
    startSyncing();
    return ()=>removeListner(); // just added this to try
  }, []);



  //TODO: find icons for stopped and idle. And perhaps animate BUSY?
  const renderIcon = (status) => {
    //STOPPED and IDLE are same here.
    if (status == 'BUSY') {
      return (
        <Icon          
          name="trending-down"
        />
      );
    } else if (status == 'IS_CONNECTING') {
      ...another icon
    }
  };

  renderIcon();

  return <>{renderIcon(status)}</>;
};


export default CommStatus;
```

The component is loaded as part of the stack navigation as follows:

```
  headerRight: () => (
    <>
    <CommStatus/>
    </>
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use App.js for that.

```html
    <Provider store={store}>

      <ParentView>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <AppNavigator />
          <AppToast />
        </View>
      </ParentView>

    </Provider>
```

so  in this case will mount only once.